# How do I unnest columns of tibble

Tags: r, unnest

Below is a tibble. I wish to [unnest](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) it. The desired tibble should contain 16 rows.

1. The first row should expand to 4 rows
2. The second row should expand to 2 rows
3. The third row should expand to 5*2 rows

The problem here is that in the third row, we have a vector of size 5 and a vector of size 2.  I want that row to expand to 5 * 2 = 10 rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  a_X_values = list(NA, c(3, NA), c(4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN)),
  a_Y_values = list(c(NaN, NaN, 3, 5), NaN, NaN),
  b_X_values = list(7, 8, c(3, NaN)),
  b_Y_values = c(NA, NaN, 1)
)

tbl1 <- tbl %>% 
  unnest(where(is.list))
```

The desired output would be

```
tbl_desired <- tibble(
  a_X_values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN, 4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN ),
  a_Y_values = c(NaN, NaN, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN),
  b_X_values = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 3, NaN, 3, NaN, 3, NaN, 3, NaN, 3, NaN),
  b_Y_values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

Comment: @akrun I have added the desired output

Comment: Hi @SiH if you have another question, please create a new post rather than tacking it on to the end of this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tidyverse`, we can use `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
reduce(1:3, unnest, .init = tbl)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   a_X_values a_Y_values b_X_values b_Y_values
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         NA        NaN          7         NA
 2         NA        NaN          7         NA
 3         NA          3          7         NA
 4         NA          5          7         NA
 5          3        NaN          8        NaN
 6         NA        NaN          8        NaN
 7          4        NaN          3          1
 8          4        NaN        NaN          1
 9          5        NaN          3          1
10          5        NaN        NaN          1
11          6        NaN          3          1
12          6        NaN        NaN          1
13        NaN        NaN          3          1
14        NaN        NaN        NaN          1
15        NaN        NaN          3          1
16        NaN        NaN        NaN          1
```

---

If it needs to pick the list columns automatically, find the column index or column names where the columns are list (from `select`) and use that in the `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
   select(where(is.list)) %>% 
   names %>%
   reduce(unnest, .init = tbl)
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   a_X_values a_Y_values b_X_values b_Y_values
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         NA        NaN          7         NA
 2         NA        NaN          7         NA
 3         NA          3          7         NA
 4         NA          5          7         NA
 5          3        NaN          8        NaN
 6         NA        NaN          8        NaN
 7          4        NaN          3          1
 8          4        NaN        NaN          1
 9          5        NaN          3          1
10          5        NaN        NaN          1
11          6        NaN          3          1
12          6        NaN        NaN          1
13        NaN        NaN          3          1
14        NaN        NaN        NaN          1
15        NaN        NaN          3          1
16        NaN        NaN        NaN          1
```

---

If we need to subset the rows based on the number of non-NA elements

```
reduce(1:3, unnest, .init = tbl) %>%
   filter(rowSums(!is.na(.[1:3])) > 1)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  a_X_values a_Y_values b_X_values b_Y_values
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1         NA          3          7         NA
2         NA          5          7         NA
3          3        NaN          8        NaN
4          4        NaN          3          1
5          5        NaN          3          1
6          6        NaN          3          1
```

---

Or if we need to do this programmatically

```
library(pipeR)
library(magrittr)
tbl %>%
   select(where(is.list)) %>% 
   names %>>%
   (~ tmp) %>% 
   reduce(unnest, .init = tbl) %>%
   filter(across(all_of(tmp), complete.cases) %>% 
               reduce(`+`) %>%
              is_greater_than(1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  a_X_values a_Y_values b_X_values b_Y_values
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1         NA          3          7         NA
2         NA          5          7         NA
3          3        NaN          8        NaN
4          4        NaN          3          1
5          5        NaN          3          1
6          6        NaN          3          1
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you make it more generic? The code should apply unnest to columns which are list. 1:3 is very specific, I could not understand that.

Comment: @SiH 1:3 are the column indexes of list columns.  As it is already known about the position, I used index directly instead of finding the index  or names of list.  UPdated in case you have a different case

Comment: I have a small request. If you can help me with that. 3 rows were extended to 16 rows, but all them do not make sense. I am only interested in rows which contains combination of real numbers. Therefore, the only useful rows are # 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11. Is there a way to reduce to these rows only.

Comment: can you please help with this.

Comment: @SiH Do you want `reduce(1:3, unnest, .init = tbl) %>% filter(rowSums(!is.na(.[1:3])) > 1)`

Comment: Thanks, can you please generalize it i.e. remove 1:3

Answer (score 3):

For sequential unnesting, I'd use a `for` loop:

```
list_cols = sapply(tbl, is.list)
for(col in names(list_cols)[list_cols]){
  tbl <- tidyr::unnest(tbl, all_of(col))
}
tbl
# # A tibble: 16 × 4
#    a_X_values a_Y_values b_X_values b_Y_values
#         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#  1         NA        NaN          7         NA
#  2         NA        NaN          7         NA
#  3         NA          3          7         NA
#  4         NA          5          7         NA
#  5          3        NaN          8        NaN
#  6         NA        NaN          8        NaN
#  7          4        NaN          3          1
#  8          4        NaN        NaN          1
#  9          5        NaN          3          1
# 10          5        NaN        NaN          1
# 11          6        NaN          3          1
# 12          6        NaN        NaN          1
# 13        NaN        NaN          3          1
# 14        NaN        NaN        NaN          1
# 15        NaN        NaN          3          1
# 16        NaN        NaN        NaN          1
```